How to navigate to type from decompiled C# code in VS Code?
In VS Code I cannot navigate to types in decompiled C# code:

#region Assembly Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerGen, Version=6.4.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=d84d99fb0135530a
The type is displayed in white color as opposed to a orange one, and it cannot be navigated to. I need to look up OpenApiSecurityRequirements to check its properties.
I'm using C# Dev Kit v1.9.55.
